# Represent data as an image when using a matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, imshow

So I have a loop which iterates through a matrix, updating it bit by bit. I Would like to represent this graphically as a moving picture. Previously I have used the canvas.draw() but am having no luck here, and am recieving the warning message

> 'local variable image is assigned to but never used'

which I can't understand because I have another piece of code where I use an identical procedure for displaying the figure, inside a loop like this one, and am not having any issues.

Also, the console is telling me the following error:

> Image data cannot convert to float

I understand that set_data() will only accept numpy or PIL but I'm confused. Is imshow the same as set_data?

```
def myfunction(tef,eps=1):


    im = plt.imshow(matrix, cmap='gray', vmin=1, vmax=1, interpolation='none')    
    for t in range(numbers):    
        i = np.random.randint(N) 
        j = np.random.randint(N) 

        if (value > 0):
            b = np.exp(-1/tef)

        else:
            b = 1
            randNum = 1
            matrix.change(i,j)
            result = True
            energycount.append(energies)

        image = plt.imshow(matrix)
        fig.canvas.draw()
        plt.pause(1)    
        plt.show()   

        t +=1

        matrix.show()

myfunction(1000)
```

I've tried to take out as much irrelevant code as possible but the problem I'm having is when I try to use the

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you, but you are in fact assigning to `image` and never using it, as far as I can tell...

Comment: I know it seems crazy but I swear I have another script where I get away with it

Comment: I dunno, what linter are you using? This isn't an error, really...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm just not sure where exactly I'm supposed to use image? When I run the code, nothing appears

Comment: You also seem to be ignoring the input `t`

Comment: Was the input parameter supposed to be called `matrix`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist which input parametre exactly?